# Java nested ifs

Tags: java, if-statement, nested

Below is a small function which when given two numbers `(a, b)`, returns `true` if one of the numbers is a teen-number. Returns `false` if both are teen. Returns `false` if both are not teen. I failed these test cases but I can't figure out why. Help? 
`(13, 99)`, `(14, 20)`, and `(16, 9)`

```
public boolean loneTeen(int a, int b) 
{
    if(a<=19 && a>=13) 
    {
        if(b<=19 && b>=13)
        {
            return false;
        } 
    }
    else if(a<=19 && a>=13)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else if(b<=19 && b>=13)
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Notice that the first `if` and the first `else if` are the same. You could easily fix it by removing that first `else if` block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All three test cases will enter first if branch, they will not match inner condition and, since they already matched first branch, will not match any of else if's. So, they will all return false which is wrong.

Comment: Ah. I see. You addressed my confusion perfectly and it makes perfect sense. I was not understanding why my code was wrong. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Using a small auxiliary method can make your life much easier (and the code more readable!):

```
private boolean isTeen(int a) {
    return a > 12 && a < 20;
}

public boolean loneTeen(int a, int b) {
    if(isTeen(a) && isTeen(b) ||
            !isTeen(a) && !isTeen(b)) {
        return false;        
    }        
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Why not just use **xor**, since you want only one of them to be true?

Comment: @mbomb007 you can do that but it makes the code less readable which is why I don't like it. This way it's written exactly as it's being described in words: "Returns false if both are teen. Returns false if both are not teen"

Comment: @mbomb007 order is ensured by [operators precedence](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html)

Answer (score 1):

First else won't be executed as you are putting the same condition on both if and else.try putting

```
if( a>=13 && a<=19 && b>=13 && b<=19){return false;}
else if(a>=13 && a<= 19){return true;}
else if(b<=19 && b>=13){return true;}
else return false;
```